# How to flatten google bigquery result in python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a large database im trying to query with the help of python and the bigquery API.

But the problem is that it returns a list of lists, and im having problems with flattening the results.

right now im doing this:

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_accoun_json('...')
query_job = client.query("""...""")
result = query_job.result()
```

And from here im lost, the list can vary from 1 level down to 3-4 levels, which makes it extremly hard to search through the results.

Is there an effective way to flatten the results?

Comment: How much data are you trying to return? My normal process is to run a SQL query and return the results as a Pandas DataFrame. Would this meet your requirements?

Comment: This is what i also do at the moment, the problem were with how to use the results afterwards. 
Which is now solved by using the UNNEST and subqueries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not really clear to me what you mean when you say that your query is reporting a list of lists with a varying number of levels.

In the BigQuery Python Client Library, `query_job` is an object of type `google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob`. In order to iterate over the results, you just need to add a loop in your code, like:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query("...")
for row in query_job:
    print(row)
```

Each `row` object contains one of the rows returned from the BigQuery query that you ran. Depending on whether you are using Standard SQL or Legacy SQL, the `row` format will be different. Standard SQL is the recommended and preferred language for querying data from BigQuery, but one of the characteristics of Legacy SQL is that [it flattens query results automatically](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated#flatten), so you may use it if nested and repeated fields are an issue for you. Otherwise, you can [flatten results in Standard SQL using the `UNNEST` operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays).

In order to work with specific fields in the query result, you should just work with the `row` object as:

- For "normal" fields: `row.field1`
- For nested fields in Standard SQL: `row.parent[0]["child"]`
- For nested fields in Legacy SQL: `row.parent_child`

In any case, by printing one of the `row` objects, you will see the available fields and how to iterate over them. In general, they can just be treated like normal Python dictionaries.

---

As a side note, in order to use Legacy SQL with the Python Client Library (it uses Standard SQL by default), you only need to add a `QueryJobConfig` parameter like:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_legacy_sql = True
query_job = client.query("...", job_config=job_config)
```

Comment: This worked for me, i went with the UNNEST operator and did more narrow queries instead. And i implemented some functions to sort through the data with the identifiers from the query. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help and you were able to get a solution working!

Answer (score 0):

For flattening of BigQuery tables with repeated fields from my point of view, it would be better to use BQ FLATTEN function.
It should work faster and will look more obvious than flattening by iterating over a repeated field in Python itself.
[flattening of repeated type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated)

So you can do something similar to:

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_accoun_json('...')
query_job = client.query('SELECT your_column from FLATTEN([dataset.tableId], repeated_column)')
result = query_job.result()
```

It would be better to check this such query in BQ UI for the amount of data will be fetched before execution.

Comment: how can I get if result has a row?